# Estimating $\int_e^x \log\log{t}\, dt$ so the error term in within $O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2{x}}\right)$

Tags: analysis, integration, asymptotics

How can one estimate the integral $$\int_e^x \log\log{t}\, dt$$ so that the error term is within $O\left(\frac{x}{\log^2x}\right)$? We may assume that $x>e$.

Any hint?

Comment: integration by part and bound logarithmic integral.

Comment: @Michael, I'm curious, what does `\nolimits` do in the integral? The new version looks the same as the old to me.

Comment: If the default value of limits will change (from current \nolimits to \limits), this integral will looks the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you integrate by parts, you end up with

$$x\log\log\,x-\int_e^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\log\,t}$$

The last bit evaluates to $\mathrm{li}(x)-\mathrm{Ei}(1)$, where $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ is the [exponential integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E5), and $\mathrm{li}(x)=\mathrm{Ei}(\log\,x)$ is the [logarithmic integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E8).

Using this [asymptotic series for the exponential integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12.E2), we obtain

$$x\log\log\,x-\frac{x}{\log\,x}\left(1+\frac1{\log\,x}+\frac2{(\log\,x)^2}+\cdots\right)$$

I've given the cookie, but it's up to you to supply the cream filling...